# How to expand/collapse table content that is too long in React, MaterialTable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, jsx

I am unable to expand / collapse content that is too long in the description column of the table. On clicking expand, the ConfirmDialog component is rendered on the page instead. Code is formatted below:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import clsx from 'clsx';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/styles';
import {
  Card,
  Avatar,
  Typography,
  Button,
  Dialog,
  DialogTitle,
  DialogContent,
  DialogContentText,
  DialogActions,
  TextField,
  CircularProgress,
  Collapse
} from '@material-ui/core';

import { Alert, AlertTitle } from '@material-ui/lab';

import { Check } from '@material-ui/icons';
import { getInitials } from 'utils/users';
import { formatDateString } from 'utils/dateTime';
import CandidateEditForm from 'views/pages/UserList/components/UserEditForm';
import CustomMaterialTable from 'views/components/Table/CustomMaterialTable';
import usersStateConnector from 'views/stateConnectors/usersStateConnector';
import ConfirmDialog from 'views/containers/ConfirmDialog';
import {
  confirmCandidateApi,
  deleteCandidateApi,
  updateCandidateApi,
  sendUserFeedbackApi
} from 'views/apis/authService';
import { updateMainAlert } from 'redux/MainAlert/operations';
import { createAlertBarExtraContentFromObject } from 'utils/objectManipulators';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {},
  content: {
    padding: 0
  },
  inner: {
    minWidth: 1050
  },
  nameContainer: {
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  avatar: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(2)
  },
  actions: {
    justifyContent: 'flex-end'
  },
  collapseContent: {
    maxHeight: 100,
    overflow: 'hidden',
    transition: 'max-height 0.3s ease-out'
  },
  expandContent: {
    maxHeight: 'none'
  },
  expandButton: {
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end'
  }
}));

const CandidatesTable = (props) => {
  const { className, mappeduserState, ...rest } = props;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [openDel, setOpenDel] = useState(false);
  const [currentCandidate, setCurrentCandidate] = useState(null);

  const [openNewMessagePopup, setOpenNewMessagePopup] = useState(false);

  const [userFeedbackMessage, setUserFeedbackMessage] = useState('');
  const [messageSubject, setMessageSubject] = useState('');
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const users = mappeduserState.candidates;
  const editCandidate = mappeduserState.userToEdit;
  const userToDelete = mappeduserState.userToDelete;

  //the methods
  const hideEditDialog = () => {
    props.mappedhideEditDialog();
  };

  const submitEditCandidate = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const editForm = document.getElementById('EditCandidateForm');
    const userData = props.mappeduserState;
    if (editForm.userName.value !== '') {
      const data = new FormData();
      data.append('id', userData.userToEdit._id);
      data.append('userName', editForm.userName.value);
      data.append('firstName', editForm.firstName.value);
      data.append('lastName', editForm.lastName.value);
      data.append('email', editForm.email.value);
      //add the role in the near future.
      props.mappedEditCandidate(data);
    } else {
      return;
    }
  };

  const hideDeleteDialog = () => {
    props.mappedHideDeleteDialog();
  };

  const cofirmDeleteCandidate = () => {
    props.mappedConfirmDeleteCandidate(mappeduserState.userToDelete);
  };

  const hideConfirmDialog = () => {
    props.mappedhideConfirmDialog();
  };

  const classes = useStyles();

  useEffect(() => {
    props.fetchCandidates();
  }, []);

  const onConfirmBtnClick = (candidate) => () => {
    setCurrentCandidate(candidate);
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const onDenyBtnClick = (candidate) => () => {
    setCurrentCandidate(candidate);
    setOpenDel(true);
  };

  const confirmCandidate = () => {
    setOpen(false);
    return confirmCandidateApi(currentCandidate)
      .then((res) => {
        props.fetchCandidates();
        dispatch(
          updateMainAlert({
            show: true,
            message: res.message,
            severity: 'success'
          })
        );
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        const errors = (error.response && error.response.data && error.response.data.errors) || {};

        dispatch(
          updateMainAlert({
            show: true,
            message: error.response && error.response.data && error.response.data.message,
            severity: 'error',
            extra: createAlertBarExtraContentFromObject(errors || {})
          })
        );
      });
  };

  const deleteCandidate = () => {
    setOpenDel(false);
    return deleteCandidateApi(currentCandidate._id)
      .then((res) => {
        props.fetchCandidates();
        dispatch(
          updateMainAlert({
            show: true,
            message: res.message,
            severity: 'success'
          })
        );
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        dispatch(
          updateMainAlert({
            show: true,
            message: err.response.data.message,
            severity: 'error'
          })
        );
      });
  };

  const modifyCandidate = (id, data) => {
    setOpenDel(false);
    return updateCandidateApi(id, data)
      .then((res) => {
        props.fetchCandidates();
        dispatch(
          updateMainAlert({
            show: true,
            message: res.message,
            severity: 'success'
          })
        );
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        dispatch(
          updateMainAlert({
            show: true,
            message: err.response.data.message,
            severity: 'error'
          })
        );
      });
  };

  const sendUserNewMessage = async (candidate) => {
    setLoading(true);
    if (messageSubject && userFeedbackMessage) {
      const body = {
        email: candidate.email,
        subject: messageSubject,
        message: userFeedbackMessage
      };

      sendUserFeedbackApi(body)
        .then((res) => {
          dispatch(
            updateMainAlert({
              show: true,
              message: res.message,
              severity: 'success'
            })
          );
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          return dispatch(
            updateMainAlert({
              show: true,
              message: err.response.data.message,
              severity: 'error'
            })
          );
        });

      setUserFeedbackMessage('');
      setOpenNewMessagePopup(false);
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  const handleExpandClick = async (candidateId) => {
    setOpen((prevOpen) => !prevOpen);
    if (!open) {
      try {
        setLoading(true);
        await props.mappedFetchFeedback(candidateId);
        setLoading(false);
      } catch (error) {
        setLoading(false);
        dispatch(updateMainAlert('Failed to fetch feedback. Please try again later.', 'error'));
      }
    }
  };

  /*
  useEffect(() => {
    if (editCandidate) {
      setOpen(true);
    }
  }, [editCandidate]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (userToDelete) {
      setOpenDel(true);
    }
  }, [userToDelete]);
*/
  return (
    <Card {...rest} className={clsx(classes.root, className)}>
      <CustomMaterialTable
        title={'candidate'}
        userPreferencePaginationKey={'candidates'}
        data={users}
        columns={[
          {
            title: 'Full Name',
            render: (user) => {
              return (
                <div className={classes.nameContainer}>
                  <Avatar className={classes.avatar} src={user.avatarUrl}>
                    {getInitials(`${user.firstName + ' ' + user.lastName}`)}
                  </Avatar>
                  <Typography variant="body1"> {user.firstName + ' ' + user.lastName}</Typography>
                </div>
              );
            }
          },
          {
            title: 'Email',
            field: 'email'
          },
          {
            title: 'Country',
            field: 'country'
          },
          {
            title: 'Category',
            field: 'category'
          },
          {
            title: 'Description',
            field: 'description',
            render: (candidate) => (
              <>
                <div
                  className={clsx(classes.collapseContent, {
                    [classes.expandContent]: open
                  })}
                >
                  {candidate.description}
                </div>
                {candidate.description.length > 100 && (
                  <div className={classes.expandButton}>
                    <Button
                      size="small"
                      color="primary"
                      onClick={() => handleExpandClick(candidate._id)}
                    >
                      {open ? 'Collapse' : 'Expand'}
                    </Button>
                  </div>
                )}
              </>
            )
          },
          {
            title: 'Organization',
            field: 'long_organization'
          },
          {
            title: 'Job Title',
            field: 'jobTitle'
          },
          {
            title: 'Submitted',
            field: 'createdAt',
            render: (candidate) => (
              <span>{candidate.createdAt ? formatDateString(candidate.createdAt) : '---'}</span>
            )
          },
          {
            title: 'Rejected',
            field: 'updatedAt',
            render: (candidate) => {
              const pending = candidate.status === 'pending';
              return (
                <span
                  style={
                    pending
                      ? {
                          padding: '5px',
                          border: '1px solid #e3e3e3',
                          background: '#e3e3e3',
                          fontWeight: 'bold',
                          borderRadius: '5px'
                        }
                      : null
                  }
                >
                  {pending
                    ? 'pending'
                    : formatDateString(candidate.updatedAt, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss')}
                </span>
              );
            }
          },
          {
            title: 'Action',
            render: (candidate) => (
              <div>
                <Button
                  disabled={candidate.status === 'rejected'}
                  color="primary"
                  onClick={onConfirmBtnClick(candidate)}
                >
                  Confirm
                </Button>
                {candidate.status === 'rejected' ? (
                  <Button
                    style={{ color: '#008CBA' }}
                    onClick={() => modifyCandidate(candidate._id, { status: 'pending' })}
                  >
                    Revert
                  </Button>
                ) : (
                  <Button
                    disabled={isLoading}
                    style={{ color: 'red' }}
                    onClick={onDenyBtnClick(candidate)}
                  >
                    Reject
                  </Button>
                )}
              </div>
            )
          },
          {
            title: 'Message',
            render: (candidate) => (
              <div>
                <Button
                  variant="outlined"
                  onClick={() => {
                    setOpenNewMessagePopup(true);
                    setCurrentCandidate(candidate);
                  }}
                >
                  Send message
                </Button>
              </div>
            )
          }
        ]}
        options={{
          search: true,
          searchFieldAlignment: 'left',
          showTitle: false
        }}
      />

      {/*************************** the edit dialog **********************************************/}
      <ConfirmDialog
        open={open}
        close={() => setOpen(false)}
        confirmBtnMsg={'Confirm'}
        confirm={confirmCandidate}
        title={'Confirm candidate'}
        message={'Are you sure you want to grant this user access?'}
      />
      <ConfirmDialog
        open={openDel}
        close={() => setOpenDel(false)}
        confirmBtnMsg={'Reject'}
        confirm={() => modifyCandidate(currentCandidate._id, { status: 'rejected' })}
        title={'Reject candidate'}
        message={
          'Are you sure you want to deny access to this candidate? This process can be reverted'
        }
        error
      />
      <Dialog
        open={props.mappeduserState.showEditDialog}
        onClose={hideEditDialog}
        aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title"
      >
        <DialogTitle></DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent></DialogContent>
        <DialogContent>
          <DialogContentText>Edit the user's details</DialogContentText>

          {editCandidate && (
            <CandidateEditForm userData={editCandidate} editCandidate={submitEditCandidate} />
          )}

          {editCandidate && mappeduserState.isFetching && (
            <Alert icon={<Check fontSize="inherit" />} severity="success">
              Updating....
            </Alert>
          )}

          {editCandidate && !mappeduserState.isFetching && mappeduserState.error && (
            <Alert severity="error">
              <AlertTitle>Failed</AlertTitle>
              <strong> {mappeduserState.error} </strong>
            </Alert>
          )}

          {editCandidate && !mappeduserState.isFetching && mappeduserState.successMsg && (
            <Alert severity="success">
              <AlertTitle>Success</AlertTitle>
              <strong>{editCandidate.firstName}</strong> {mappeduserState.successMsg}
            </Alert>
          )}
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={hideEditDialog} color="primary" variant="contained">
            cancel
          </Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>

      {/***************************************** deleting a user ***********************************/}

      <Dialog
        open={props.mappeduserState.showDeleteDialog}
        onClose={hideDeleteDialog}
        aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title"
      >
        <DialogContent>
          <DialogContentText>Delete Candidate</DialogContentText>

          {props.mappeduserState.userToDelete && !userToDelete.error && !userToDelete.isFetching && (
            <Alert severity="warning">
              <AlertTitle>Warning</AlertTitle>
              Are you sure you want to delete this user —{' '}
              <strong>{props.mappeduserState.userToDelete.firstName}</strong>?
              <strong> {mappeduserState.error} </strong>
            </Alert>
          )}

          {mappeduserState.userToDelete && mappeduserState.error && (
            <Alert severity="error">
              <AlertTitle>Failed</AlertTitle>
              <strong> {mappeduserState.error} </strong>
            </Alert>
          )}

          {mappeduserState.userToDelete && !mappeduserState.error && mappeduserState.isFetching && (
            <Alert severity="success">
              <strong> Deleting.... </strong>
            </Alert>
          )}

          {!mappeduserState.userToDelete && !mappeduserState.error && !mappeduserState.isFetching && (
            <Alert severity="success">
              <AlertTitle>Success</AlertTitle>
              Candidate <strong> {mappeduserState.successMsg}</strong>
            </Alert>
          )}
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          {!mappeduserState.successMsg && !mappeduserState.isFetching && (
            <div>
              <Button onClick={cofirmDeleteCandidate} color="primary">
                Yes
              </Button>
              <Button onClick={hideDeleteDialog} color="primary">
                No
              </Button>
            </div>
          )}
          {mappeduserState.successMsg && !mappeduserState.isFetching && (
            <Button onClick={hideConfirmDialog}>Close</Button>
          )}
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
      <Dialog
        fullWidth
        maxWidth={'sm'}
        open={openNewMessagePopup}
        onClose={() => setOpenNewMessagePopup(false)}
        aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title"
      >
        <DialogContent>
          <DialogContentText>Message Candidate</DialogContentText>
          <div style={{ marginBottom: '16px' }}>
            <TextField
              autoFocus
              id="subject"
              onChange={(e) => setMessageSubject(e.target.value)}
              label="Subject"
              type="text"
              variant="outlined"
              fullWidth
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <TextField
              autoFocus
              id="message"
              onChange={(e) => setUserFeedbackMessage(e.target.value)}
              label="Message Body"
              type="text"
              multiline
              rows={8}
              variant="outlined"
              fullWidth
            />
          </div>
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button
            disabled={isLoading}
            onClick={() => setOpenNewMessagePopup(false)}
            variant="outlined"
          >
            Cancel
          </Button>
          <Button
            disabled={isLoading}
            onClick={() => sendUserNewMessage(currentCandidate)}
            color="primary"
          >
            Finish
          </Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </Card>
  );
};

CandidatesTable.propTypes = {
  className: PropTypes.string,
  candidates: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  fetchCandidates: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default usersStateConnector(CandidatesTable);
```

I tried removing the setOpen function from the handleExpandClick() because it seems to set the open state variable to true which triggers the ConfirmDialog component to render. This did not solve the issue however.